# Hazards of charging an opened circuitry lithium-ion battery?

Tags: batteries, lithium

I was opening a Toshiba Excite 7 tablet which stopped charging. Tablet turns on without issues when battery is not connected, but does not when it is present.

I decided to check the little pcb circuit of the battery and i "sliced" around 2 centimeters of the plastic that "hugs" the innards of it. At first i did not realize I was just in the innards. It is not punctured, but i did discovered solvent smell from the battery right were i sliced the plastic.

If i want to connect this battery to the tablet and try charging it, what could go wrong?

[image]

Comment: Batteries have warning labels saying not to mistreat them for a reason. Stop what you're doing before you hurt yourself.

Comment: That's exactly what i did. Stopped poking with this tablet completely, and will dispose the battery correctly. Also the failure on this Toshiba tablet is the battery itself, it is dead. I was just wondering if there is any hazard on trying to charge this battery, i thought it had some kind of hermetical enclosure but learned roughly there is not.

Comment: It's not punctured? You jabbed its entire head off! I can see the barrier foil!

Comment: "What could go wrong?"..famous last words?

Comment: I meant punctured like... stabbed? This is exactly why i wanted to ask random people on the internet, i'm pretty stubborn to fix things up. Sometimes we need someone telling us... "Stop"

Comment: @Mascareño  [Lithium battery puncture test.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvUjIWEVRnY)  Notice the shield and other precautions.

Comment: Hey guys, and what about using a little duct tape? :DD

@NickAlexeev I bet it works yet... *cringe* Yea, lots of safety preparations. Interesting video

Comment: You have already invited gasses and moisture into your battery. Anything you do now to close it back up is just turning it into a hand grenade, rather than a blow torch.

Comment: Correct. Just catched your edit on answer below. Just want to add that some minutes ago I was speaking with a friend, and he told me that a guy died recently here in my region, because his smartphone exploded due to an incorrect repair procedure. Screen was cracked, and replaced by some shop. It got that big that the shop is being legally prosecuted for negligence. It's interesting how sometimes things revolve around you.

Comment: @Mascareño I find, just about nothing (may be rounded down) really ever revolves around me.

Answer (score 2):

Once you smell the solvent the pack goes to Chemical Recycling, however hard that may be in your local region. Period. No using, whatsoever. Ionic exchange in the batteries can create hydrogen gas. (Edit: Which is infinitely more likely with moisture from the air you just let in)

Especially when the environment is no longer hermetic.

Comment: I'll dispose of the battery properly. Thanks for your answer. Fascinating how batteries work, i'll dig a little bit more on the chemical aspect you pointed out.